# Intellij IdeaVim plugin - run current file

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

Is it possible to call Intellij IDE actions with IdeaVim plugin (via some bindings maybe)?

For example:

```
:runfile
```

Will run current Java class.

I know about Quick Action Menu <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, but I want to use IDE in Vim style.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use :action and :actionlist commands.

Comment: Cool! `:action Run` works perfectly! Now I just wonder about shortcuts for moving the cursor to and from the console and hiding/opening it.

Comment: Use `:action Debug` to debug current file. To move focus back to editor, use Esc. Shift + Esc will also close the run console and move focus back to editor. To open run/debug console, use cmd + 4 and cmd + 5 respectively in Mac.